# Hashing - Separate Chaining - Efficiently dealing with repetitive numbers

Tags: hashtable

I am constructing a hash table mod 17 for example and I am trying to figure out an efficient way to deal with a repeating key value. Suppose I have like a random number generator and I make a 1000 random generated numbers, there is a chance that some of those numbers might occur multiple times. My implementation would have a linked list to an array for each of the slots i.e. 17 slots and keys would be stored in their respective position.

I want to kind of implement a failsafe sort of checker function that insures that there are no repeating keys in the hash table. I have been looking this up on the internet and have not found a most definite answer. MY idea was to keep each linked list sorted and have a lookahead to check if the number is there already. Does anyone know of a better idea?

Any thoughts and comments greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want multiple values for the same key? I think it is not possible. When you go to retrieve the value, which value would you choose.

Comment: No I do not want repetitive values, I want to check if it is there already and prevent it from being added